# Collectionview inside tableview cell indexpath issue

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uicollectionviewcell

Im using collection view inside my `tableview` cell.

For this I made a `tableview` cell class and inside it define `collectionview`. i have 2 secions for `collectionview` and Im getting the issue right now of setting `indexpath` as I required `indexpath` to check which index of collection clicked .

```
    #pragma mark - UITableViewDelegate
    - (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView willDisplayCell:(FifaPlanTableViewCell *)cell forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
        [cell setCollectionViewDataSourceDelegate:self indexPath:indexPath];
    }


interface FifaPlanCollectionView : UICollectionView
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSIndexPath *indexpath;
@end


    @interface FifaPlanTableViewCell : UITableViewCell
    @property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet FifaPlanCollectionView *collectionViewFifa;

    - (void)setCollectionViewDataSourceDelegate:(id<UICollectionViewDataSource, UICollectionViewDelegate>)dataSourceDelegate indexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath;

- (void)setCollectionViewDataSourceDelegate:(id<UICollectionViewDataSource, UICollectionViewDelegate>)dataSourceDelegate indexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    self.collectionViewFifa.delegate = dataSourceDelegate;
    self.collectionViewFifa.dataSource = dataSourceDelegate;
    self.collectionViewFifa.indexpath = indexPath;

    [self.collectionViewFifa reloadData];
}
```

At this point `self.collectionViewFifa.indexpath = indexPath`; application is crashing saying:

```
Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[UICollectionView setIndexpath:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7fa7aa016000'
```

Can anyone let me know what I'm doing wrong here?

Comment: Did you set class name for the collction view in xib or storyboard ?

Comment: yes i have set the class to FifaPlanCollectionView in storyboard

Comment: @SyedFarazHaiderZaidi Try to change the variable name of indexPath in FifaPlanCollectionView.

Comment: i change it to other name also but it is still not working

Comment: @SyedFarazHaiderZaidi Just remove the     [self.collectionViewFifa reloadData] method guess its reloading infinite time.

Comment: @SyedFarazHaiderZaidi All of cells on tableView are FifaPlanTableViewCell. Is it right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may try using `cellForRowAtIndexPath` instead of `willDisplayCell`,

```
-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
FifaPlanTableViewCell *cell = (FifaPlanTableViewCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"MyIdentifier"];
[cell setCollectionViewDataSourceDelegate:self indexPath:indexPath];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Suppose click event from cell

[cell.buttonInstance addTarget:self action:@selector(getIndexActionMethod:event:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

-(void) getIndexActionMethod:(UIButton*)sender event:(UIEvent *)events
{

UITouch *touch = [[events allTouches] anyObject];

```
CGPoint touchPos = [touch locationInView:self.tableViewInstance];

NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.tableViewInstance  indexPathForRowAtPoint:touchPos];
```

}